# C daemon execute system() in Android

Tags: android, c

I have compiled a C daemon that runs on Android (Android 6)

```
-rwxrwxrwx root     root       715940 2017-09-21 14:51 server.o
```

the daemon runs fine, and responds to requests from clients. However, I would like to initiate a system() call from the daemon, for example:

```
system("mkdir /data/test/");
```

this fails (any system() call I made failed, reference on Linux, same code
different Makefile works fine). The Android is rooted. Please advice how to perform system() commands from C daemon on Android.

Comment: No [mcve]. On a sidenote: why invoke the shell and an external program? Shooting the head through the knee?

Comment: I will explaine, I need an application to invoke gpio setting, I2C setting etc... the simplest way is to create a C deamon that will communicate with the Android application. do you suggest another way?

Comment: What is the return value from system()? Is mkdir on the $PATH for your process? What if you run /system/bin/mkdir?